# Obtain a ManagedConnectionFactory - Resource Adapter on JBoss 7

Tags: java, oracle, authentication, migration, jboss7.x

I am migrating an application from JBoss 4 to JBoss 7 and facing a problem with the login module

My application have a custom login module for Oracle DB that checks the user and pass against oracle users.
It obtains a ManagedConnectionFactory with a configuration like this

```
<security-domain name="client-login" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="org.custom.OracleLoginModule"
<module-option name="managedConnectionFactoryName" value="jboss.jca:service=LocalTxCM,name=datasourceName"/>
```

That works in JBoss 4, as far as I understand because this JBoss have in deployments a resource adapter jboss-local-jdbc.rar
The resource adapter creates a local ManagedConnectionFactory that can be obtained with that name.

The relevant code for JBoss 4 is:

```
MBeanServer server = MBeanServerLocator.locateJBoss();
return (ManagedConnectionFactory) server.getAttribute(managedConnectionFactoryName, "ManagedConnectionFactory");
```

But in JBoss 7 that MBean appears to not exist.
Is there a resource adapter like that in JBoss 7 that can be used?
Do I need to program my own Resource Adapter?

I have made a solution creating via java code a ManagedConnectionFactory:

```
...
LocalManagedConnectionFactory factory = new LocalManagedConnectionFactory();
    factory.setDriverClass("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    factory.setConnectionURL(CONNECTION_URL);
    factory.setUserName(user);
    factory.setPassword(password);
...
```

But I'm not sure this is a good solution, it doesn't use the configured datasource... 
Is there any problem creating a LocalManagedConnectionFactory in this way?

As you can see I have some doubts and questions, thanks in advance.